# How to Count the Object Properties values and Displaying the serparate values in Dynamic button and assign click event to them

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, typescript

Here i getting data dynamically what i am doing is i am displaying the dynamic data and placing the data with marker .Till showing the Dynamic maps i fine but in the below issues i am stuck i dont know how to move forward

**Dynamic data:**

```
{
    "page": 2,

    "data": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "first_name": "Eve",
            "last_name": "Holt",
            "lat":"25.6599899",
            "lng":"45.3664646",
            "status":"0"

        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "first_name": "Charles",
            "last_name": "Morris",
            "lat":"25.99899",
            "lng":"45.4646",
             "status":"1"

        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "first_name": "Tracey",
            "last_name": "Ramos",
            "lat":"25.2339899",
            "lng":"45.56664646",
            "status":"1"

        }
    ]
}
```

**Issue 1:  In the **Status** the value in **0** here i have to count how many 0 and 1 are there

Issue 2: After Counting Suppose if Status 1 is Contain 3 people and then all the 3 People name separately had to be displayed in the form of button(Dynamically) if 0 means that one separately

Issue 3 After creating the Dynamic button if i click on the button   with some name  then on the map an info window has to be displayed with that specified marker which is already placed with that person**

below is my Dynamic Marker Code

```
    addMarker(latlng, mapobj, markerLabel,iconColor) {

          this.iconDisplay =[];

         if(iconColor === "0"){
            this.iconDisplay = this.red;

         }else if(iconColor === "1"){
             this.iconDisplay = this.green;

         }else if(iconColor === "2"){
             this.iconDisplay = this.orange;

         }else if(iconColor === "3"){
          this.iconDisplay = this.building;
      };


        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          //zoom:this.zoomlevel,
          position: latlng,
          map: mapobj,
          icon:this.iconDisplay

        });

      debugger
        mapobj.setCenter(latlng);

        mapobj.setZoom(parseInt(localStorage.getItem('getz')));


        mapobj.addListener('zoom_changed', function() {
          mapobj.getZoom();
          localStorage.setItem('getz',mapobj.getZoom());
        });

    const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: markerLabel
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
     //infowindow1.open(Map,marker);

    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'mouseover', function() {
      infowindow.open(Map,marker);
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'mouseout', function() {
    infowindow.close();
});

  //This is for by default opening infowindow
    // infowindow.open(Map, marker);

    const styless = [
      {
        "featureType": "poi.attraction",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },

      {
        "featureType": "poi.medical",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi.park",
        "elementType": "labels.text",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi.place_of_worship",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi.school",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi.sports_complex",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]

    mapobj.setOptions({styles: styless});
    // This is for set postion for the marker after getting dynamic data it posittions to the point

  mapobj.panTo(marker.position);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count up the number of zeros and ones with `.reduce`:

```js
const input = {
  "page": 2,
  "data": [{
      "id": 4,
      "first_name": "Eve",
      "last_name": "Holt",
      "lat": "25.6599899",
      "lng": "45.3664646",
      "status": "0"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "first_name": "Charles",
      "last_name": "Morris",
      "lat": "25.99899",
      "lng": "45.4646",
      "status": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "first_name": "Tracey",
      "last_name": "Ramos",
      "lat": "25.2339899",
      "lng": "45.56664646",
      "status": "1"

    }
  ]
}
const { zeroCount, oneCount } = input.data.reduce( ({ zeroCount = 0, oneCount = 0 } = {}, { status }) => {
  if (status === '0') zeroCount++;
  if (status === '1') oneCount++;
  return { zeroCount, oneCount }
}, {});
console.log('Zeros: ' + zeroCount + ' , Ones: ' + oneCount);
```

Comment: Ok What about my other 2 issues is there any solution for that

Comment: Note that SO questions should be about *one* thing, not three (questions that aren't are liable to be closed for being too broad)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by taking reference from my code below:

```
const input = {
    "page": 3,
    "data": [{
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "Niraj",
        "last_name": "Paudel",
        "lat": "454.454",
        "lng": "454545",
        "status": "0"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "Kushal",
        "last_name": "Shrestha",
        "lat": "235.99899",
        "lng": "452.4646",
        "status": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "first_name": "Ritesh",
        "last_name": "Sainju",
        "lat": "253.3439899",
        "lng": "423.56664646",
        "status": "1"

    }
    ]
}


let statusZeroObj  = input.data.filter(e => e.status === 0);
let statusOneObj = input.data.filter(e => e.status === 1);

//Issue 1
const countOfStatus0 = statusZeroObj.length;
const countOfStatus1 = statusOneObj.length;

//Issue 2
//suppose you need to append button with name "for status zero" in div id container0
statusZeroObj.forEach(function(statusZeroPerson) {
    addBtn('#container0', statusZeroPerson);
});

//suppose you need to append button with name "for status one" in div id container1
statusOneObj.forEach(function(statusOnePerson){
    addBtn('#container1', statusOnePerson);
});

function addBtn(id, person) {
    let btn = document.createElement("input");
    btn.type = button;
    btn.name =  person.first_name;
    btn.onClick = addMarker(person); //I am not totally sure what you want to do with marker
    document.getElementById(id).appendChild(btn);
}


// Issue 3
const addMarker = function(person) {
// implement the logic for marker
}
```

Comment: In the above function addBtn use btn.onClick instead of element.onClick. May be it caused the issue!

Comment: any way i created button using the *ngFor